# Play audio on touchstart

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, touch, html5-audio

I have a problem playing some audio after a touchstart. I have the following code which I run in Chrome 57 to do so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Play Media on user touch</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="play">Click me to play audio!</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
                                new Audio('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3').play()        
   })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I open this on my mobile device and testing for touchstart, I get this error in console:

> Warning: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only
>   be initiated by a user gesture.
>
> Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.

Is touchstart not considered a user gesture? Is this intentional behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't play for the first time only, after user clicked anywhere - sound can be played

Answer (score -1):

A few months ago, I set chrome flag 
chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback to true
and play on touchstart event worked properly in chrome.
Unfortunately, this flag disappeared last time, after updating chrome.

Now, I'm working around the problem by using firefox in my mobile. It's now a ideal solution, but I didn’t find something better.
It's strange for me that chrome uses other implementation of js then others.